# When I group by a PK, all columns from that table have the same value in each group. So why does SQL Server require aggregation for those columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Preface

There is a general rule for using grouping in SQL: If you want to reference a column in the select clause, you must either wrap it in an aggregation function, or you must include it in the group by clause. In understand this rule and the reasons for it. My question is about a special case where I think there should be an exception to this rule: when two or more tables are joined and are being grouped by one table's primary key.

---

Consider two tables (table_A and table_B). If I group on table_A's PK, any other column belonging to table_A will have the same value within each group. This is necessarily the case. It is always so. I feel that SQL Server should allow me to include other columns from table_B without needing to wrap them in agg functions.

Here's what I would like to work:

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,A.f_name
    ,A.l_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN table_B B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
GROUP BY
    A.id
```

Instead, I get this error:

> Column 'table_A.f_name' is invalid in the select list because it is
> not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I've thought of workarounds, but I'm not happy with any of them.

### Workaround 1 - Superflous Aggregation

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,MIN(A.f_name) AS first_name
    ,MIN(A.l_name) AS last_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN table_B B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
GROUP BY
    A.id
```

Results:

```
average_score first_name last_name
------------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross      
11            Ricky      Bobby     
12            Rick       Ross
```

I don't like this since it obscures the meaning of the code; We're not *really* taking the min value here. In fact, it doesn't matter which agg function we choose: MIN() and MAX() both return the same thing.

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,MAX(A.f_name) AS first_name
    ,MAX(A.l_name) AS last_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN table_B B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
GROUP BY
    A.id
```

Results:

```
average_score first_name last_name
------------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross      
11            Ricky      Bobby     
12            Rick       Ross
```

This highlights that all values from table_A are truely the same within each group, and why I don't think I should be forced to use agg functions on references to table_A columns since table_A's PK is being grouped on.

### Workaround 2 - Unnessesary Grouping

Here we group by every column that appears in the select clause without an agg function.

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,A.f_name
    ,A.l_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN table_B B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
GROUP BY
    A.f_name
    ,A.l_name
    ,A.id
```

Results:

```
average_score f_name     l_name
------------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross      
11            Ricky      Bobby     
12            Rick       Ross
```

Once again, I feel the meaning of the code is obscured. What we want is to make every person their own group of one. However, this reads as if we're putting everyone into groups based on shared first name, then dividing those groups further based on last name. Since some people may share the same first and last name, we still find necessary to group by the PK to ensure groups of one person each. However, if we'd just grouped by the PK in the first place, we could've accomplished this in one go. This is syntactically inefficient (not sure if the actual performance is any worse, but it reads like it's doing some extra work - not straightforward).

### Workaround 3 - Redundant Subqueries

Here we have subqueries in the select clause rather than joins.

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,(SELECT A.f_name FROM table_A A WHERE A.id = B.table_A_id) AS first_name
    ,(SELECT A.L_name FROM table_A A WHERE A.id = B.table_A_id) AS last_name
FROM table_B B
GROUP BY
    B.table_A_id
```

Results

```
average_score first_name last_name
------------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross      
11            Ricky      Bobby     
12            Rick       Ross
```

I don't like this either, since we have to repeat almost the same subquery for each column from table_A we want to return. Tables A and B are begging to be joined. The problem gets worse the more data we want in the resultset, especially if we need to go through table_A to get it.

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,(SELECT A.f_name FROM table_A A WHERE A.id = B.table_A_id) AS first_name
    ,(SELECT A.L_name FROM table_A A WHERE A.id = B.table_A_id) AS last_name
    ,(SELECT C.team FROM table_C C WHERE C.id = (SELECT A.table_C_id FROM table_A A WHERE A.id = B.table_A_id)) AS team_name
FROM table_B B
GROUP BY
    B.table_A_id
```

Results:

```
average_score first_name last_name  team_name
------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross       Team A    
11            Ricky      Bobby      Team A    
12            Rick       Ross       Team B
```

Here is the same logical query but using an earier workaround:

```
SELECT
    AVG(B.score) AS average_score
    ,MIN(A.f_name) AS first_name
    ,MIN(A.l_name) AS last_name
    ,MIN(C.team) AS team_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN table_B B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
JOIN table_C C ON C.id = A.table_C_id
GROUP BY
    A.id
```

Results:

```
average_score first_name last_name  team_name
------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
12            Bob        Ross       Team A    
11            Ricky      Bobby      Team A    
12            Rick       Ross       Team B
```

Do you all find this similarly frustrating? Does anyone have a more elegant workaround here that the ones I thought of?  Do other DBs have the same issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Very good question. I wondered about this time ago. You are talking about "functional dependency". The SQL Standard does not force you to aggregate the non-pk columns, but the implementations of SQL in the database engines do. I'm sorry, life is what it is.

Comment: @TheImpaler And then there's the other side of the coin, where MySQL used to let you use the columns even if they were not functionally dependent and would just use the first value in the group, for whatever "first" happened to mean for that particular execution plan... which definitely did violate the standard.

Comment: "not sure if the actual performance is any worse, but it reads like it's doing some extra work - not straightforward" it is almost certainly the same. SQL Server is very good at working out function dependencies automatically, so `A` would not be re-sorted. "Workaround 2" is the only reasonable idea, the others are less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does SQL Server require aggregation for those columns

As explained in the other answer because SQL Server does not implement the capability allowed for in the SQL Standard to project functional dependencies of a key that is already being grouped by.

> Do other DBs have the same issue?

[Apparently not for the following](https://blog.jooq.org/functional-dependencies-in-sql-group-by/#:%7E:text=At%20least%20the%20following%20SQL%20dialects%20support%20this%20language%20feature)

- CockroachDB
- H2
- HSQLDB
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Yugabyte

> Does anyone have a more elegant workaround here that the ones I
> thought of?

I would write the query as follows and collapse the "many" side down before the join. There is then no need for any `GROUP BY` involving `table_A` at all.

```
WITH AggB AS
(
SELECT AVG(B.score) AS average_score,
       table_A_id
FROM table_B
GROUP BY table_A_id
)
SELECT 
     B.average_score
    ,A.f_name
    ,A.l_name
FROM table_A A
JOIN AggB B ON B.table_A_id = A.id
```

As the aggregation is only really on `table_B` columns I find this cleaner anyway and it is often required if you want to add a join to another table with a many to one relationship to `table_A` (as otherwise `sum`s can be incorrectly multiplied out)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the comment, most database engines don't implement the *functional dependency* that the SQL Standard defines. In theory you wouldn't need to aggregate non-pk columns when grouping by the PK.

The exception, of course, is PostgreSQL that adheres to functional dependency. Isn't PostgreSQL great? (I'm not affiliatted in any shape or form with those guys, btw). You're out of luck if using SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, or MySQL, though.

For example, see this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/YheClDoa) in PostgreSQL:

```
create table t (id int primary key not null, a int);

insert into t (id, a) values (1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 260);

select id, a from t group by id; -- Works as you wanted!

select id, a from t group by a; -- Fails as you would expect
```

In the third SQL statement is not necessary to aggregate `a`, since `a` is functionally dependent on `id`.

But `id` is not functionally dependent on `a`. You can see that the fourth query fails when we try something similar.

This is especially useful when joining tables through associations (1:0-1) or collections (1:0-n). In these cases even the related columns of other tables can still fall under the "functional dependency" rule making the query much shorter and simpler to write and to debug.

Comment: mysql does implement a sort of grouping like this. Although, they probably only care about values being the same, not functional dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I'll push for Postgres next time! I'm glad to add "functional dependence" to my vocab